# Filtering a list of objects with a certain attribute

Tags: c#

```
class Object
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string description {get; set;}
}
```

If I have a `List<Object> Objects` populated with various objects, and I want to find objects whose description is something particular, how would I do that?

```
find every Object in Objects whose description == "test"
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var results = Objects.Where(o => o.Description == "test");
```

---

On a side note, realize that `Object` is a very poor choice of names for a class, and won't even compile as-is...  I'd recommend choosing more appropriate names, and following standard capitalization conventions for C#.

Answer (score 3):

Like Reed Copsey answered `LINQ`. +1.

My answer is still with `LINQ`, but with my prefered way of writing it:

```
var results =   from myobject in myobjects 
                where myobject.description == "test"
                select myobject;
```

In the where parameter, you could put in any predicate (a function returning a bool).

```
var results =   from myobject in myobjects 
                where MyPredicate(myobject)
                select myobject;
```

Comment: Just FYI - this is no more "modern" - my version and this one both became available in the same compiler release ;)

Comment: I really thought it was added in a newer version of C#.

Comment: Nope - Both were adding in C# 3.  The integrated query syntax you used compiles to the same thing, but my version still requires extension methods and lambdas - all 3 were part of C# 3.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try

```
foreach(Object obj in Objects)
{
    if(obj.description.Contains("test"){
        //Object description contains "test"
    }
}
```