# How to Filter results in ASP.net core based on a data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, filter

I am able to get a List of data inside a variable. Now, what I want is to **filter** it on the basis of a value **IsDeleted**. If the value of **IsDeleted** is **true** I don't have to show that result and exclude it from the List, else I have to show the data.

Here's my code for the Same:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Vendor>> Get()
    {
        var VendorList = context.Vendor.ToList();
        return Ok(VendorList); 
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a list of objects with a certain attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253548/filtering-a-list-of-objects-with-a-certain-attribute)

Comment: `var Filtered = VendorList.Where(x=>x.IsDeleted == true)` should work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering collections in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196/filtering-collections-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) clause to do filter.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Vendor>> Get()
{
    var VendorList = context.Vendor.where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
    return Ok(VendorList); 
}
```