# lookup to provide collection member counts by property value

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Person
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    int Age {get; set;}
}

public List<Person> persons;
```

I need a lookup data-structure such as `Dictionary<int,int>` that provided an age gives me the count of persons of that age.

EDIT : here's the answer :

```
return persons.GroupBy(m => m.Age).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Hope that helps someone else who comes across this post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a list of objects with a certain attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253548/filtering-a-list-of-objects-with-a-certain-attribute)

Comment: `persons.Count(x => x.Age == age)`

Comment: Which property do you want to use für the look up? In your comment you say that you want a string as the key and int as a value but in your code you do the opposite

Comment: @Mong Zhu sorry I had a typo - what I want is `Dictionary<int,int>` so for the lookup key `age` return the count of persons with `Person.Age = age`

Comment: @EdPlunkett I never changed my requirements. Look at the post history : the title has remained the same `lookup to provide collection member counts by property value`.  `lookup` is a noun not a verb. You misread the question and `ToDictionary()` is not a complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really is that simple.

```
var counts = persons.GroupBy( p => p.Age ).ToDictionary( g => g.Key, g => g.Count() )
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

```
//Query Syntax
var counts = (from p in persons
              group p by p.Age)
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

//Method Syntax
var counts = persons.GroupBy(p => p.Age).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

Then, `counts` can be used as a dictionary with key age and value count.

## Detailed Explanation:

When a `GroupBy` is used in this situation, it creates an `IEnumerable` of  `IGrouping`.

This structure, while similar to a `Dictionary`, does not have all of the same properties. An `IGrouping` itself is an implementation of `IEnumerable`, and acts somewhat like a column in a spreadsheet, in that all the values inside of it are tied to a `Key`, like a column has a header.

To then put this into a `Dictionary`, the `IEnumerable<IGrouping>` must be flattened. To do this, each `IGrouping` must be converted into a `KeyValuePair`. (Please note that it does not explicitly need to be a `KeyValuePair`, but that this is the effective result.) In this example, this is done by setting the `Key` of each `KeyValuePair` to the age, and the `Value` of the `KeyValuePair` is typically some sort of aggregate function, such as `Count` or `Sum`, or even just the `IEnumerable` of associated values itself.

In the following solution, the conversion step is done all at once. `ToDictionary` is applied to an `IEnumerable<T>`, and requires two main things: A way to get a key from each item (`T`), and a way to get a value from each item. With our current setup, the `Key` of each `IGrouping` is the Age, so we pass that over with the first lambda: `x => x.Key`. After that, we give it a selector for the value. We want the number of people with that age, so the expression is: `x => x.Count()`.

The main difference between an `IEnumerable<IGrouping>` and a `Dictionary` is that an `IEnumerable<IGrouping>` can have multiple `IGrouping`s with the same key, although there is usually not a reason to do so.

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem I ran into - how to get count from `IGrouping`

Comment: Seeing as Crusha already specified the method syntax version, I'll edit my answer to explain what it's doing. I know I personally ran into trouble my first few times trying to convert into a dictionary using LINQ.

Comment: awesome detail @FlutterDashie this is actually a very useful post for newbies to LINQ and doesn't deserve -6 downvotes